# Encrypting connectionStrings in a web.config file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, encryption

Any section in my web.config file that I want to encrypt I run this command line util:
aspnet_regiis -pe "anySection" -app "/SampleApplication"

It all works just fine until I try encrypt my connectionStrings sections

I define (and I cannot change this) my connectionStrings section like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>      
</connectionStrings>
```

But the "standard" way of defining it is like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myName" connectionString="...." providerName="..." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

How when I run:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"
```

It errors with "...Unrecognized attribute 'key'....". If I change the connection string section to be the standard way it works fine. But I CANNOT use this format.

Is there a way of doing this using the aspnet_regiis util? Doing it with code is not an option for me.

Also is there a way to run this untility without specifing the application (-app "/SampleApplication") instead giving the path to the web.config file?

thanks a million

Comment: If you are doing things in a non-standard way, you can't expect automated tools to work.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question, why are you using an non-standard method to do the connectionString beyond the fact its a legacy system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've copied and pasted an `appSetting`

`<add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>` is invalid since `key` and `value` are not an attributes the `connectionString` element expects.

You will have to use the "standard"

`<add name="myName" connectionString="...." />`

---

[connectionStrings Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi hunter. I haven't copied and pasted an appSetting, I copied and pasted a section called "connectionStrings" (I could have called it testSection or anything) that has a key value pair (just like the app settings). This is a legacy system and what I need to be able to do is use that utility on sections that have a key-value pair. Is this not possible? And why not, I don't see the problem?

Comment: `aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" ` is looking for `name` and `connectionString`. It doesn't know what to do with `key` and `value`. using `key` and `value` in the `connectionStrings` element is invalid as defined by the schema.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't supposed you know if I can supply a path to the web.config file instead of giving the application name?

Answer (score 2):

The add element inside the connectionStrings element has a well-defined schema (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htw9h4z3.aspx) and it is not the same element as the add element inside the appSettings element.

If you want to encrypt the appSettings section, and that would be the **entire** appSettings section, you can do this:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't supposed you know if I can supply a path to the web.config file instead of giving the application name?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but in theory, yes. Use the -pef argument instead of the -pe and -app arguments. For example, if your web.config file is located in physical directory C:\Sites\MySite, then:
aspnet_regiis -pef "appSettings" "C:\Sites\MySite" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when I did not run the command line as an administrator.